# How to make speech to text in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to make recognition in russian language, now I am trying to do it in English. I get this exception:

```
[TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'Voice.startSpeech')]
```

This is my code react-native app with the error:

```
const Train = () => {
  const [user] = useAuth()
  const [pitch, setPitch] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [end, setEnd] = useState('');
  const [started, setStarted] = useState('');
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const [partialResults, setPartialResults] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
      //Setting callbacks for the process status
      Voice.onSpeechStart = onSpeechStart;
      Voice.onSpeechEnd = onSpeechEnd;
      Voice.onSpeechError = onSpeechError;
      Voice.onSpeechResults = onSpeechResults;
      Voice.onSpeechPartialResults = onSpeechPartialResults;
      Voice.onSpeechVolumeChanged = onSpeechVolumeChanged;

      return () => {
          //destroy the process after switching the screen
          Voice.destroy().then(Voice.removeAllListeners);
      };
  }, []);

  const onSpeechStart = (e) => {
      //Invoked when .start() is called without error
      console.log('onSpeechStart: ', e);
      setStarted('√');
  };

  const onSpeechEnd = (e) => {
      //Invoked when SpeechRecognizer stops recognition
      console.log('onSpeechEnd: ', e);
      setEnd('√');
  };

  const onSpeechError = (e) => {
      //Invoked when an error occurs.
      console.log('onSpeechError: ', e);
      setError(JSON.stringify(e.error));
  };

  const onSpeechResults = (e) => {
      //Invoked when SpeechRecognizer is finished recognizing
      console.log('onSpeechResults: ', e);
      setResults(e.value);
  };

  const onSpeechPartialResults = (e) => {
      //Invoked when any results are computed
      console.log('onSpeechPartialResults: ', e);
      setPartialResults(e.value);
  };

  const onSpeechVolumeChanged = (e) => {
      //Invoked when pitch that is recognized changed
      console.log('onSpeechVolumeChanged: ', e);
      setPitch(e.value);
  };

  const startRecognizing = async () => {
      //Starts listening for speech for a specific locale
      try {
          await Voice.start('en-US');
          setPitch('');
          setError('');
          setStarted('');
          setResults([]);
          setPartialResults([]);
          setEnd('');
      } catch (e) {
          //eslint-disable-next-line
          console.error(e);
      }
  };

  const stopRecognizing = async () => {
      //Stops listening for speech
      try {
          await Voice.stop();
      } catch (e) {
          //eslint-disable-next-line
          console.error(e);
      }
  };

  const cancelRecognizing = async () => {
      //Cancels the speech recognition
      try {
          await Voice.cancel();
      } catch (e) {
          //eslint-disable-next-line
          console.error(e);
      }
  };

  const destroyRecognizer = async () => {
      //Destroys the current SpeechRecognizer instance
      try {
          await Voice.destroy();
          setPitch('');
          setError('');
          setStarted('');
          setResults([]);
          setPartialResults([]);
          setEnd('');
      } catch (e) {
          //eslint-disable-next-line
          console.error(e);
      }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
            <Image
                source={require('../assets/images/Logo_small.png')}
                style={styles.logo_s}
                resizeMode='contain'/>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.main_cont}>
            <Train_word marginBottom={34}/>
            <Train_word_2 marginBottom={55}/>
            <Pressable marginBottom={190} onPress={startRecognizing}>
                <Image
                    source={require('../assets/images/Start_img.png')}
                    style={styles.start_img}>
                </Image>
            </Pressable>
            <Pressable style={styles.result} onPress={''}>
                <Text style={styles.text_result}>Получить результат</Text>
            </Pressable>
        </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

The code Always takes the exception. I do not know how to solve it.

How can I fix this and make speech to text in russian language. Help me please, I am a beginner in react native.